# NullPointerException calling SvnAnt's Copy.setRevision

Tags: ant, svnkit, svnant

I'm trying to perform SVN copy operation (creating a tag from a branch) using Java.

I'm getting the below exception.

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnFacade.getFacade(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnFacade.getSetting(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnFacade.getDateFormatter(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.commands.SvnCommand.getDateFormatter(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.commands.SvnCommand.getRevisionFrom(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.commands.Copy.setRevision(Unknown Source)
>
> at svnOperation.createTags.commitTags(createTags.java:55)
>
> at svnOperation.createTags.main(createTags.java:23)"

I'm using the latest SVN JAR files.

Could someone please suggest how to correct this or what mistake I'm doing here.

Here is my code:

```java
Project p = new Project();
p.setProperty("username", "automation");
p.setProperty("password", "automation");
p.setProperty("javahl", "true");
p.setProperty("javahl", "true");
SvnTask svn = new SvnTask();

Copy C1 = new Copy();

C1.setDescription("Creating tags");
C1.setSrcUrl(new SVNUrl("SrcUrl"));
C1.setDestUrl(new SVNUrl("DestUrl"));
C1.setMessage("message");
C1.setRevision("1234"); 
C1.setProject(p);

svn.addCopy(C1);
svn.setProject(p);
svn.execute();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

SvnAnt is designed to be used from Ant scripts. However, it appears you're trying to interact with Subversion with Java code.

[SVNKit](https://svnkit.com/) is the better way to access Subversion features from within a Java application.

Here is an example of creating a Subversion tag:

```java
SVNCopyClient copyClient =
    SVNClientManager.newInstance().getCopyClient();

SVNURL srcURL = SVNURL.parseURIEncoded("http://example.com/repos/trunk");
SVNURL dstURL = SVNURL.parseURIEncoded("http://example.com/repos/tags/tag");
SVNCopySource copySource =
    new SVNCopySource(SVNRevision.HEAD, SVNRevision.HEAD, srcURL);

copyClient.doCopy(new SVNCopySource[] {copySource}, dstURL,
    false, false, true, "message", null);
```

See [Getting Started With SVNKit](https://wiki.svnkit.com/Getting_Started_With_SVNKit) for more.

Comment: We added Authentication to svn url and we are facing Exception in thread "main" org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: File not found: revision 1540882, path 'srcURL'
svn: '/svn/sag/!svn/bc/1540882/srcURL' path not found: 404 Not Found (http://svnva.ame.ad.sag:1818) . Please let me know if anything else i need to add to copy srcURL to dstURL.

Comment: Authentication 'DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();
  SVNRepository repository = null;
  repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded("Repository URL"));
        ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager("auto", "auto");
        repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);'

Comment: Calling SVNCopyClient 'SVNURL srcUrl =SVNURL.parseURIEncoded("SrcURL");
SVNURL dstUrl=SVNURL.parseURIEncoded("DstUrl");
SVNClientManager SM = SVNClientManager.newInstance();
SM.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
SM.createRepository(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded("RepoUrl"), true);SVNCopyClient copyClient=SM.getCopyClient();
SVNCopySource copySource=new SVNCopySource(SVNRevision.HEAD, SVNRevision.HEAD, srcUrl);
SVNProperties P =  new SVNProperties();
P.put("username","auto");
P.put("password","auto");
copyClient.doCopy(new SVNCopySource[]{copySource},destUrl,false,true,false,"message",P);'

Comment: And we have given valid srcURL

Comment: For example srcURL is http://{host}/svn/aaa/eb/tags/99main. I'm facing svn: File not found: revision 1540902, path '/eb/tags/99main/eb/tags/99main'(appending the srcURL to srcURL not sure why)

/1540902/eb/tags/99main' path not found: 404 Not Found (http://{}host:{port}).

Comment: This line isn't right: `SVNURL srcUrl =SVNURL.parseURIEncoded("SrcURL")`. It should be: `SVNURL srcUrl =SVNURL.parseURIEncoded("http://{host}/svn/aaa/eb/{your_branch_here}")`.

Comment: Hi , Line is correct just for sake of example i mentioned SVNURL srcUrl =SVNURL.parseURIEncoded("SrcURL");  we are using SVNURL srcUrl =SVNURL.parseURIEncoded("http://{host}/svn/aaa/eb/{your_bran‌​ch_here}");  as you mentioned in previous comment. we assume that some where in "SVNCopySource" or "doCopy" , scrURL is getting appended again.